# Load an image using MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to MFC Dialog application.
I want to create a dialog which allows me to open a bitmap image.
I am able to open the the file. But now I wish to double click on a BitMap file and launch my application.
Please tell me how to do it.
I saw this code to get the image path.

```
char* buff;
char* command_line = GetCommandLine();

buff = strchr(command_line, ' ');
buff++;

if (buff != NULL)
{
    pMainFrame->OpenFile(buff);
}
```

But it gives error that `GetCOmmandLine()` is of type LPWSTR and cannot be converted into char*.

Comment: You should start to Google it. It can be easily found.

Comment: I googled it. I am able to display a saved image.
But can't find where to give the path to display the user selected image.

Answer (score 0):

`MSDN` is a wonderful place to start if you want to learn about MFC : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/482ck6x8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx . There are a lot of examples which you can tinker with.

For your application, you need the `CFileDialog` object to bring a popup for the file selection, and a `CImage` object for image manipulation and storage.